# Get matching phrase from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My application so far gets the word entered into a text box, then checks the database column if there is the exact same matching string, then displays the results in the view.

my controller:

```
 public function questions()
{
    //Pick up what was typed in the text box named "query"
    $question = $this->input->get("query"); 
    //Extract the correct data from the model.
    $details = $this->questions_model->lookup($question); 
    $x = $details->result();
    print"<pre>";print_r($x);print"</pre>";
    print gettype($x);
    //Display data on the web page.
    $this->load->view('findquestions', array('items' => $x)); 
}
```

my model:

```
public function lookup($question_category) {
    $resultsset = $this->db->get_where('question', 
    'question_title = "' .  $question_category . '"');
    return $resultsset;
}
```

my view:

```
<form action='/cw2/index.php/search/questions' method="GET">
    Find Question: <input type="text" name="query">
</form>


<?php 
  if (isset($items)) {
    foreach($items as $i){
      print $i->question_title . " " . $i->question_category;
    } 
  }
?>
```

If I search 'red' and there is a title called 'red' in the db table column it will be displayed in the result.

However if I search 'red' and there is a title called 'big red car' in the db table coloumn, I also want that to be returned in the result, since at the moment it doesnt.

Perhaps a 'stristr' type of function can be used? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Like Query

```
public function lookup($question_category)
{
$resultsset = $this->db->get_where('question', 
  'question_title like "%' .  $question_category . '%"');
return $resultsset;
}
```

Comment: Great
is there a way to display the results in json